# Using the value from paste buffer in expression register in vim

Tags: vim

Is it possible do something like

```
<cursor>25
cw<C-r>=""*2
50<cursor>
```

I want to change the word and then use the expression register to multiple what I just cut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close.

```
cw<C-R>=<C-R>"*2<CR>
```

Comment: This just seems to drop me back into insertion mode when I hit the first enter.

Comment: That's correct, because I wasn't paying attention and typed `<CR>` instead of `<C-R>` for the second `<C-R>`. Thanks for catching that. Sorry about the mistake. I've corrected the answer.